# How to use commands like 'ls & pwd' inside ftp [on own server & not on remote server]?

Tags: unix, ftp

How to use commands like 'ls & pwd' inside ftp [on own server & not on remote server] ?
By default on ftp prompt all the commands works on the remote server. How to use commands on the own server inside ftp prompt, if possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the exclamation command

```
! [command [args]]
```